Reactivity Lost in Vue Composition API when Integrating TanStack Query with Vee Validate
I'm having a reactivity issue in Vue.js when trying to integrate a custom hook with TanStack Query and Vee-Validate. I've created a custom hook using @tanstack/vue-query for data fetching, which should be reactive to changes in the form values managed by Vee-Validate's useForm.
Here's the custom hook I've created:
import { supabase } from '@modules/supabase';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/vue-query';
import { MaybeRef } from 'vue';

export function useServicesTitleList(
  currentServiceType: MaybeRef<string | undefined>
) {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['servicesTitleList', currentServiceType],
    initialData: [],
    enabled: !!currentServiceType,
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (!currentServiceType) return [];

      const { data } = await supabase
        .from('SomeTable')
        .select('*')
        .eq('type0', currentServiceType);

      return (
        data?.map((d) => ({
          label: d.display,
          value: d.display,
        })) ?? []
      );
    },
  });
}

In my component I've the following
const { handleSubmit, isSubmitting, values } = useForm({
  validationSchema: toTypedSchema(schema),
  initialValues: {},
});

const { data: titleOpts, isFetching: loadingTitles } = useServicesTitleList(
  toRef(values, 'type')
);

The issue is that the reactive values. type from Vee-Validate's useForm doesn't trigger updates in my custom hook. As a result, the enabled property in useQuery isn't being set to true when the type changes.
Can anyone provide suggestions on how to make the useServicesTitleList hook reactive to the changes in type from Vee-Validate's values?
Thanks for any help!

Solved using this code
const { data: titleOpts, isFetching: loadingTitles } = useServicesTitleList(
  toRef(values, 'type') // Transform to ref otherwise it's not
);

import { supabase } from '@modules/supabase';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/vue-query';
import { MaybeRef, computed, toValue } from 'vue';

export function useServicesTitleList(
  currentServiceType: MaybeRef<string | undefined>
) {
  
  // Need to create a computed because `enabled` requires a ref and we can't do the logic outside of a computed otherwise it's not a ref anymore
  const enabled = computed(() => !!toValue(currentServiceType));

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['servicesTitleList', currentServiceType],
    initialData: [],
    enabled,
    queryFn: async () => {
      const val = toValue(currentServiceType);

      if (!val) return [];

      const { data } = await supabase
        .from('SomeTable')
        .select('*')
        .eq('type0', val);

      return (
        data?.map((d) => ({
          label: d.display,
          value: d.display,
        })) ?? []
      );
    },
  });
}

